# for each empties my array(noob)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

First of all as probably you will get from my code I am a noob and trying to build a link crawler, that searches a page for links -> then follows each link and puts the link into an array. At the end we should have all the links found on that website.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php

$to_crawl = "http://reteteculinare.ro";
$c = array();
$final = array();

function get_Links($to_crawl){
    global $c, $final;
    $input = @file_get_contents($to_crawl);
    $base_url = parse_url($to_crawl, PHP_URL_HOST);

    $regexp = '<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>';
    preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches);

    $l = $matches[2];

    foreach ($l as $link) {

        if(strpos($link, "#")) {

            $link = substr($link, 0, strpos($link, "#"));

        }

        if(substr($link, 0, 1) == "."){

            $link = substr($link, 1);

        }

        if(substr($link, 0, 7) == "http://"){

            $link = $link;

        } else if (substr($link, 0, 8) == "https://"){

            $link = $link;

        } else if (substr($link, 0, 4) == "www."){

            $link = substr($link, 4);

        } else if (substr($link, 0, 6) == "//wwww."){

            $link = substr($link, 6);

        } else if (substr($link, 0, 2) == "//"){

            $link = substr($link, 2);

        } else if (substr($link, 0, 1) == "#"){

            $link = $to_crawl;

        } else if (substr($link, 0, 7) == "mailto:"){

            $link = "[".$link."]";

        } else {

            if(substr($link, 0, 1) != "/") {

                $link = $base_url."/".$link;

            } else {

                $link = $base_url.$link;

            }

        }

        if(substr($link, 0, 4) == "www."){

                $link = substr($link, 4);

        } 

        if(substr($link, 0, 7) != "http://" && substr($link, 0, 8) != "https://" && substr($link, 0, 1) != "[") {

            $link = "http://".$link;

        }

        if (!in_array($link, $c)) {

            array_push($c, $link);

        }


    }

}

get_links($to_crawl);

foreach ((array)$c as $page) {

    get_links($page);

    foreach ((array)$c as $page) {

        if (!in_array($page, $final)) {

            $final[] = $page;
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($final);
            echo '</pre>';
        }

    }

}

?>
```

The problem in the current code is that it prints the array every time a new page is added and we get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://reteteculinare.ro/autentificare/
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://reteteculinare.ro/autentificare/
    [1] => http://reteteculinare.ro/inregistrare/
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://reteteculinare.ro/autentificare/
    [1] => http://reteteculinare.ro/inregistrare/
    [2] => http://reteteculinare.ro/
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://reteteculinare.ro/autentificare/
    [1] => http://reteteculinare.ro/inregistrare/
    [2] => http://reteteculinare.ro/
    [3] => http://reteteculinare.ro/retete/
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://reteteculinare.ro/autentificare/
    [1] => http://reteteculinare.ro/inregistrare/
    [2] => http://reteteculinare.ro/
    [3] => http://reteteculinare.ro/retete/
    [4] => http://reteteculinare.ro/mixer-ingrediente/
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://reteteculinare.ro/autentificare/
    [1] => http://reteteculinare.ro/inregistrare/
    [2] => http://reteteculinare.ro/
    [3] => http://reteteculinare.ro/retete/
    [4] => http://reteteculinare.ro/mixer-ingrediente/
    [5] => http://reteteculinare.ro/reteta_saptamanii/
)
...
```

Note: - tried putting the print at the end of the second foreach, I still get more than one arrays.
- tried putting the print after the first foreach, it doesn't output anything.

What am I doing wrong, how can I get the $final array to be printed after all the script is complete?

Cheers!

Comment: print it after `foreach` is over.

Comment: If I print it after the second foreach, I will still get more then 1 array. If I print it after the first foreach, the array is empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `print_r($final);` outside of `foreach`

Comment: If I move after the first foreach the print function I still get more arrays with the added pages, If I move it after the second foreach, I get an empty array.

Comment: So whats your issue.Print your results after first foreach

Comment: Was trying to achieve just 1 array containing all the links, if putting the print after the second array I get more than 1 arrays, if after first I get nothing..